# Deny and allow rules for IP address not working when using nginx in docker compose

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, rules

I have a service behind an nginx docker compose container , but i can only deny and accept all i can't narrow it to sepcific IP or IP ranges. Basically i want just on ip on my local network to be able to access that application behind a nginx proxy

I have tried using proxy_protocol but that fails with the error  *2 broken header: "GET / HTTP/1.1" while reading PROXY protocol, client: 172.18.0.1, server: 0.0.0.0:80